# Google Data Studio: cumulative column

Tags: mysql, looker-studio

I have a MySQL database connected to Google Data Studio with columns including 'date' and 'new users'. The 'new users' column has the number of new users per day.

I would like to plot a graph of the cumulative number of users against date. This would be easy to do in a spreadsheet (by adding a column that adds up a running total), but I can't figure out if it's possible in Data Studio.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 10):

I also looked for a solution to the same problem and it is actually quite simple:

## For Data Sources

You might want to take a look at the calculated fields, for example the `COUNT()` function to adapt your data source: https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/6299685?hl=en

## Using the Time Series Graph

I wanted to visualize the data directly, and then it is even easier.
If you have a time series graph, you can just switch the settings under `Style -> Line` and then check the `Cumulative` checkbox:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Cumulative on the time series style is the best solution. If you have single rows of data, input a column that is SUM(1) and after that assigning 1 to each entry, and then using cumulative to track over a time series.